# Setting the full with of an element?

Tags: html, css, width

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style>
            .child {
                background-color: red;
                width:33.3%;
                height:200px;
                float:left;
            }

            .wraper {
                width:80%;
                height:600px;
                margin:auto;
                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wraper">
            <div class="child">
                <p>some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="child">
                <p>some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="child">
                <p>some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to set up a little layout and I'm wondering about something strange: I have to set the width of the childs to 33.3**3**%, otherwise there is a bit of spacing on the right side. Is that the right way? And something similar: What if I want to set a border around the childs of 5px. Do I really have to try which percentage number fits? Or is there another way to set the full width of a child, including the border, margin and padding to a fixed percentage number? I think I need a little explanation of how these things work in html.

Answer (score 0):

The way to set the full width in CSS is by using the `box-sizing` :

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

More info about : http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/